# section wise add up data

Tags: mysql, sql, r

hello as the title suggest i need to sum section wise data --->

```
can.id       status            qid    marks
001    section 1 question 1    112     3
001    section 1 question 2    117     3
001    section 1 question 3    116     3
001    section 2 question 1    115     3
001    section 2 question 2    114    -1
001    section 2 question 3    111     3
001    section 3 question 1    112    -1
001    section 3 question 2    116     3
002    section 1 question 1    114     3
002    section 1 question 2    111     3
002    section 2 question 2    111    -1
002    section 3 question 1    111    -1
```

i want to display sum of marks for each can.id for every section, help is appreciated....

Comment: Do you need a `R` solution as there is a `r` tag?

Comment: take out status from your group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can use `dplyr`.  We `extract` (from `tidyr`), substring from 'status' to create 'section', then grouped by 'can.id' and 'section', get the `sum` of 'marks'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  extract(status, into = "section", "(.*\\d+)\\s+[[:alpha:]].*") %>%
  group_by(can.id, section) %>% 
  summarise(SumMarks = sum(marks))
#  can.id   section SumMarks
#   <int>     <chr>    <int>
#1      1 section 1        9
#2      1 section 2        5
#3      1 section 3        2
#4      2 section 1        6
#5      2 section 2       -1
#6      2 section 3       -1
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(SumMarks = sum(marks)), .(can.id, 
                 section = sub("\\s+[[:alpha:]].*", "", status))]
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(can.id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L), status = c("section 1 question 1", "section 1 question 2", 
 "section 1 question 3", "section 2 question 1", "section 2 question 2", 
 "section 2 question 3", "section 3 question 1", "section 3 question 2", 
 "section 1 question 1", "section 1 question 2", "section 2 question 2", 
 "section 3 question 1"), qid = c(112L, 117L, 116L, 115L, 114L, 
  111L, 112L, 116L, 114L, 111L, 111L, 111L), marks = c(3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, -1L, 3L, -1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, -1L, -1L)), .Names = c("can.id", 
 "status", "qid", "marks"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this with some SQL.

The issue you appear to have is that your section needs to be split out from the status field, you could do something like this;

```
SELECT
    [can.id]
    ,SUBSTRING([status],1,8) Section
    ,SUM(marks) Total
FROM samp_data
GROUP BY
    [can.id]
    ,SUBSTRING([status],1,8)
```

If you just want the top 3 for each group, check the related link below

[How to select top 3 values from each group in a table with SQL which have duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720525/how-to-select-top-3-values-from-each-group-in-a-table-with-sql-which-have-duplic)

Comment: Take a look at the link in my answer. If you have any further questions then it would probably be best to post another question.