# Mysql group by customer and get last 3 records

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Sql Table               
Sales Date  order Id    customer_id medium  
07-07-2018  WP241530914666620   26  4   
21-07-2018  WP241532133344497   26  4   
29-07-2018  WP241532821589511   26  4   
01-07-2018  1100070191  61  3   
05-07-2018  1100071337  61  3   
11-07-2018  1100073077  61  3   
15-07-2018  1100074754  61  3   
21-07-2018  1100075959  61  3   
25-07-2018  1100077484  61  3   
01-07-2018  100207654   64  3   
07-07-2018  100210077   64  3   
08-07-2018  WP241531004708220   64  4   

Result:-                
Sales Date  order Id    customer_id medium  
07-07-2018  WP241530914666620   26  4   
21-07-2018  WP241532133344497   26  4   
29-07-2018  WP241532821589511   26  4   
01-07-2018  1100070191  61  3   
05-07-2018  1100071337  61  3   
11-07-2018  1100073077  61  3
```

i need mysql query for above result .

last 3 orders for each customers in above table . i am trying some codes but unable to get results for the above

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you have tried to write?

Comment: @patrick3853 This question was asked almost a year ago.

Comment: @EternalHour Oh, thanks for pointing that out. It showed up on top of my feed for some reason, and I didn't even look at the date.

Comment: Recently edited questions will show in top questions no matter the age.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select top 3 values from each group in a table with SQL which have duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720525/how-to-select-top-3-values-from-each-group-in-a-table-with-sql-which-have-duplic)

Answer (score 0):

You could using correlated subqueries like:

```
select Sales_Date,order_Id,customer_id,medium 
from
(select y1.Sales_Date,y1.order_Id,y1.customer_id,y1.medium,
(select count(*) 
from 'yourtable' y2 
where y2.customer_id=y1.customer_id 
and (y2.Sales_Date < y1.Sales_Date or y2.Sales_Date = y1.Sales_Date)
) rn 
from 'yourtable' y1
) finalresult 
where rn<=3
```

Reference:

[correlated subqueries](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/correlated-subquery.php)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721423/7786739)