# MySQL SELECT 8 unique users, then SELECT all records within those 8 users, then SELECT 4 most recent and available records of each 8 users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database (dates are just examples for order sake)...

```
 ---------------------
| user | item |  date |
 ---------------------
|    1 |    a |   123 |
|    3 |    b |   124 |
|    1 |    c |   125 |
|    2 |    d |   126 |
|    5 |    i |   127 |
|    4 |    e |   128 |
|    6 |    f |   129 |
|    9 |    g |   130 | 
|    3 |    h |   131 |
|    9 |    s |   132 |
|    1 |    j |   133 |
|    2 |    k |   134 |
|    1 |    l |   135 |
|    1 |    m |   136 |
|    1 |    n |   137 |
|    8 |    o |   138 |
|    5 |    p |   139 |
|    9 |    q |   140 |
|    7 |    r |   141 |
 ---------------------
```

I would like to get all records up to the first 8 unique users, which would make the results...

```
 ---------------------
| user | item |  date |
 ---------------------
|    1 |    a |   123 |
|    3 |    b |   124 |
|    1 |    c |   125 |
|    2 |    d |   126 |
|    5 |    i |   127 |
|    4 |    e |   128 |
|    6 |    f |   129 |
|    9 |    g |   130 | 
|    3 |    h |   131 |
|    9 |    s |   132 |
|    1 |    j |   133 |
|    2 |    k |   134 |
|    1 |    l |   135 |
|    1 |    m |   136 |
|    1 |    n |   137 |
|    8 |    o |   138 |
 ---------------------
```

Then from those records, I'd like to get the most recent 4 records *per unique user*, making the results look like...

```
 ---------------------
| user | item |  date |
 ---------------------
|    3 |    b |   124 |
|    2 |    d |   126 |
|    5 |    i |   127 |
|    4 |    e |   128 |
|    6 |    f |   129 |
|    9 |    g |   130 | 
|    3 |    h |   131 |
|    9 |    s |   132 |
|    1 |    j |   133 |
|    2 |    k |   134 |
|    1 |    l |   135 |
|    1 |    m |   136 |
|    1 |    n |   137 |
|    8 |    o |   138 |
 ---------------------
```

Ideally I would be able to do this with one query. The closest I've been able to come is with this query:

```
SELECT users, 
GROUP_CONCAT(items) 
FROM db 
GROUP BY users 
ORDER BY date 
LIMIT 8
```

But GROUP_CONCAT gives back all results for that user, not just the amount in the selection.

I've also tried...

```
SELECT users
FROM db AS u1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT users FROM db) AS u2 ON u1.users = u2.users
```

from another suggestion I found but this also didn't work.

I've tried a ton of other things that I didn't really save because they didn't work and I was pretty confident I'd figure it out, but it's been two weeks and I haven't got close. If any SQL gurus are out there that can point me in the right direction, that would be really great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this can help you.

```
--get all records up to the first 8 unique users,depending on there first order date
 select distinct a.user,a.date as first_order_date from yourtable as a where 
 a.date = (select MIN(date) from yourtable as b where a.user=b.user) order by a.date LIMIT 8
```

Then using above result to get the most recent 4 records per unique user like below:

```
select * from yourtable as t where t.date in 
(select date from yourtable as t2 where t.user=t2.user order by t2.date desc LIMIT 4 ) and 
t.user in (select distinct a.user,a.date as first_order_date from yourtable as a
where a.date = (select MIN(date) from yourtable as b where a.user=b.user) order by a.date LIMIT 8)
```

References:

[correlated subqueries](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/correlated-subquery.php)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721423/7786739)