# How to get the top X results of a given category using Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

### Background

I have to queries that return a colossal amount of data on their own. I cannot use `Repo.all` as doing so would materialize these into memory, which would then quickly run out.

So I am trying to push as much as I can to the pSQL DB, and force the DB to do as much work as possible.

My issue starts with 2 queries.

This ones counts fruits and veggies and aggregates everything into a neat map.

```
all_counts =
      table_A
      |> join(:left, [item_A], item_B in table_B,
        on:
          item_A.home_id == item_B.home_id and
            item_A.path == item_B.path
      )
      |> select([unfiltered_item, filtered_item], %{
        path: item_A.path,
        item_fruits_count: coalesce(item_A.fruits, 0),
        item_veggies_count: coalesce(item_B.veggies, 0),
        dataset_id: item_A.home_id
      })
      |> subquery()
```

The second one, joins 2 tables as well (items and photos), with nothing fancy:

```
file_info =
      table_C
      |> join(:inner, [item], file in table_D,
        on:
          item.id == file.item_id and not file.deleted
      )
      |> select([item, file], %{
        item_id: item.id,
        home_id: item.home_id,
        path: item.path,
        photo_key: file.photo_key
      })
      |> subquery()
```

### Problem

Now the problem is that I need to merge these 2 together.
At first, one would think to do something like this:

```
result =
      all_counts
      |> join(:inner, [c], f in ^file_info, on: c.home_id == f.home_id and c.path == f.path)
      |> select([c, f], %{
        item_id: f.item_id,
        home_id: f.home_id,
        path: f.path,
        photo_key: f.photo_key,
        # ... you get the idea
      })
      |> Repo.all()
```

But this creates an issue, namely, the it will return so much data, the machines will run out of memory.

### Approach

The approach I am using to solve this problem is to group items by `home_id` and `path` (since that is unique for each destination) and then return only a portion of the data I need, lets say, the top 3 items ordered by id.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721423/1337392

Here is where my difficulties begin.
I cannot use pSQL directly, I must use Ecto (for reasons beyond this post).

Normally I would use CTEs or `row_number()`:

With ctes:

```
 WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT name, value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name
                              ORDER BY value DESC
                             )
             AS rn
    FROM t
  )
SELECT name, value, rn
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY name, rn ;
```

With `row_number`:

```
SELECT name, value, rn
FROM 
  ( SELECT name, value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name
                              ORDER BY value DESC
                             )
             AS rn
    FROM t
  ) tmp 
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY name, rn ;
```

However, I am not familiar enough with Ecto to know how to use them.

With CTEs, I understand I should avoid them, as they serve no purpose in Ecto:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#with_cte/3

With `row_number()`  I would need to partition by both `home_id` and `path` (2 fields) instead of one:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.WindowAPI.html#row_number/0

### Question

How do I get the `result`, to return the top 3 results, grouped by `home_id` and `path` and ordered by `item_id` using Ecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution(s)

From what I gathered, there are two decent possible solutions to this conundrum.

#### `row_number` + `over`

One of them is using `row_number()` with `over()` from Ecto:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.WindowAPI.html#row_number/0

Assuming I join both `file_info` with `all_counts` in a single table, I can then perform the query as mentioned in the previous SO post I mentioned in my question:

```
file_info_with_counts
|> select([fi], %{
        rn: over(row_number(), partition_by: [fi.home_id, fi.path], order_by: [asc: fi.item_id]),
        item_id: fi.item_id,
       # you get the idea ...
      })
|> subquery()

IO.inspect(file_info_with_counts |> where([c], c.rn <= 3) |> Repo.all()
```

Which prints what I wanted.

Source:
https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-get-the-top-x-results-of-a-given-category-using-ecto/53805/9?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

#### Lateral inner joins

However, as mentioned by some people in the community, this solution is rather old, and these days lateral joins seem to also cover this use case.

```
tops = 
  from top in "file_info_with_counts", 
    where: top.home_id == parent_as(:parent).home_id,
    where: top.path == parent_as(:parent).path,
    order_by: [asc: top.item_id],
    limit: 3,
    select: %{id: top.id}

from parent in "file_info_with_counts",
  as: :parent,
  group_by: [parent.home_id, parent.path],
  lateral_join: top in subquery(tops), 
  on: true,
  select: %{home_id: parent.home_id, path: parent.path, item_id: top.id}
```

Source:
https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-get-the-top-x-results-of-a-given-category-using-ecto/53805/11?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

This solution is not without merit, however, given my familiarity with `row_number` I opted for that solution instead.

Unless there is a considerable performance difference between the two in favor of lateral joins, I will keep the previous solution.

For more info, here is the original source where I got these answers:
https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-get-the-top-x-results-of-a-given-category-using-ecto/53805/8